# Computer destroys pendrive's boot possibility

Tags: boot, usb

Very strange, but tested.

I made boot USB for Windows10 (media tool). And I install it on few computers. Than I put it into IT. And it runs, but I decided to break installation for one file which I forgot to copy. Than I try to boot it again - "Non system disk or disk not ready". I put it into another machine - the same. When I connect it run-time - all files looks good. Strange. A decided to do it later.

Later I decided not to install Win10, but linux. I go to the shop, buy another one pendrive. Next I made a boot usb using unetbootin with Debian x64. I put it in THE machine, run and i saw: "Its 686 processor you can't install x64 debian" - Yes, of course! So I made a boot usb again using unetbootin with Debian x32. I put it in THE machine And.... "Non system disk or disk not ready". I put it into another machine - "Non system disk or disk not ready". I try to make unetbootin again - "Non system disk or disk not ready".

It looks that the machine destroys my bootsector in pendrive (or installs something bad). Do you have any ideas how to format pendrive again? I don't want to go again and spent more cash...

Comment: "I decided to break installation for one file which I forgot to copy" - you broke the installation. What exactly did you do?

Comment: break = abort. But the problem wasn't with installation but with booting but... see answer

Comment: @SledgehammerPL - Clarify your question by editing it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, the solution is more strange than question... In desperacy I decided to use USB hub... And... it works. Yes, I repeat. I put USB pendrive into USB port, and can't boot, than I put passive USB hub into THE SAME port and pendrive boots.

Informatics isn't science. It's magic.